# A question on Villani's monograph "Hypocoercivity"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, differential-operators

[image]

[image]

I can not figure out the appearance of the term $\int h_0\,d\mu$ in the statement of Theorem 35 above. Here are some background information: $L$ is an unbunded operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^1$, whose kernel is $\mathcal{K}$, the notation $\mathcal{H}^1/\mathcal{K}$ represents $\mathcal{K}^\perp$, $\mu$ is some reference measure of the form $\mu(dx\,dv) = f_\infty(x,v)dx\,dv$, where $f_\infty(x,v)$ is a probability density in both $x$ and $v$ variables. My question is: since Theorem 35 is a direct application (ignoring technical details), shouldn't the conclusion (from Theorem 18) $\|\mathrm{e}^{-tL}\|_{H^1(\mu)/\mathcal{K} \to H^1(\mu)/\mathcal{K} } \leq C\,\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda\,t}$ translates to $$\|\mathrm{e}^{-tL}\,h_0\|_{H^1(\mu)} \leq C\,\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda\,t}\|h_0\|_{H^1(\mu)}?$$ Why the term $\int h_0\,d\mu$ suddenly appears out of the blue? Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to handle the kernel though. I don't know his notation, but is it the case that (a) constant functions are in $H^1(\mu)$ and (b) the constant functions comprise the entirety of the kernel of $L$?

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, in the particular case under Theorem 35's consideration, $\ker(L)$ contains only constant functions. Also, constant functions are in $H^1(\mu)$ (as $\mu$ is a probability measure in the space $x$ and velocity $v$ variables)

Comment: Then in this case the projection of $h_0$ to $H^1/K$ is exactly $h_0 - \int h_0 ~d\mu$, and $e^{-tL}$ acts trivially on the latter factor.

Comment: @WillieWong I understand that $e^{-tL}\left(h_0 - \int h_0 \,d\mu\right) = e^{-tL}\,h_0 -  \int h_0 \,d\mu$, but why do you say that "the projection of $h_0$ to $\mathcal{K}^\perp$ is exactly $h_0 - \int h_0 \,d\mu$"?

Comment: @WillieWong Continuing on my previous comment, why shouldn't the conclusion be $\|\mathrm{e}^{-tL}\,h_0 - \int h_0\, d\mu\|_{H^1(\mu)} \leq C\,\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda\,t}\|h_0 - \int h_0 \, d\mu\|_{H^1(\mu)}$

Comment: Let $\langle, \rangle$ be the Hilbert space inner product, and $\mathbf{1}$ the constant function 1, it should be the case (I'm not sure since you didn't give the precise defintion of $H^1(\mu)$) that $\langle \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{1}\rangle = 1$, and  $\langle h_0,\mathbf{1}\rangle = \int h_0 ~d\mu$, and so the constant function $ (\int h_0 d\mu) \mathbf{1}$ is the projection of $h_0$ to the kernel. So subtracting it is the projection to the orthogonal complement.

Comment: And so $\|h_0 - \int h_0 d\mu\| \leq \|h_0\|$, since projections have norm 1.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! Fully agree know! (To be precise, orthogonal projections have norm $1$).